# Bōten/Wakiten (Japanese emphasis symbol) in [p]LaTeX

Tags: symbols, typography, emphasis, japanese

This may be a rather obscure matter, but I recently attempted to find an easy way of emphasizing Japanese text  using [bōten/wakiten](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2018/03/furigana-dots-bouten.html) (furigana dots) in a document I am writing using [p]LaTeX. So far I have not found any answers on this matter, probably due to the obscurity of this issue and other limitations. Is there any clean way to do this (I could include visually similar marks as furigana, but this fails in the case of expressions that already contain furigana for instance)?

Comment: Could you provide a small example document with some signs that you want to emphasize? Also an example of the desired output (e.g., a screenshot of your pdf with freehand drawing in a Paint program) would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`pxrubrica`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pxrubrica) package, which originally aimed to provide [JLReq](https://www.w3.org/TR/jlreq/)-compliant ruby, is the best way to use boten and kenten. Here are a very basic usage and its output (the optional argument `s` changes the emphasis mark to the secondary one):

```
\documentclass{jsarticle}
\usepackage{pxrubrica}
\begin{document}
\kenten{圏点}と\kenten[s]{傍点}。
\end{document}
```

[image: preview of the mwe]

The package prepares several interfaces to customize the kenten features and please refer to the Japanese documentation if you are interested. The package also has an English documentation but it only mentions ruby.